# How to get data form database on the bases of timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `products` table in which I have all the products that are being sold or ready to sell.

Here is table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `Product_Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product_Status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sell_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Every time a product is being sold its status becomes `1`.

I am trying to get all the products sold on yesterday.How would I do that in `sql` query.

```
Select Product_Name from products where status = 1 and Sell_date = ??
```

My questions is how to go back A whole day or `N` number of days in `timestamp`.

Comment: Googling a little on your issue will give you solution. Please refer to - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html  Eg. `SELECT DATE_SUB('2014-08-09', INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Answer (score 1):

For products sold in the $N last days :

```
SELECT
   Product_Name 
FROM products 
   WHERE status = 1 
   AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `Sell_date`, NOW()) <= $N
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product_Name
FROM products WHERE status = 1 and Sell_date = DATE_SUB( Sell_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

> DATE_SUB function is used for substract preticular time interval from the given date i think this will helpful to you.

Comment: This wont return anything, since this will subtract exactly one day from the sell_date and return the previous day with same time interval as today's and we may not necessarily having same time interval on the previous day.